# Fixed footer always must stay at the bottom, and respond to window resizing

Tags: html, css

[This link to the image, where I resize the window, footer must stay at the screen and table shrink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5wtk.png)

Here is a simple example of the code after Andrei Gheorghiu helped me:

```
<main>
 <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
          ...content of the table here...
 </table>
 </div>
 </main>
 <footer>
 <div class="container">This is footer</div>
 </footer>

 <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      min-height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
     }
    main {
       flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
    .container {
        width: 80%;
       margin: 0 auto;
       padding: 1rem;
      }
      footer {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        background-color: #eee;
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        background:orange;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work and it doesn't require a ***fixed footer height***.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}
footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">This is main content</div>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="container">This is footer</div>
</footer>
```

In order to have [97.38%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) browser support, it needs prefixing:

```css
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      min-height: 100vh;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
         -moz-box-orient: vertical;
         -moz-box-direction: normal;
          -ms-flex-direction: column;
              flex-direction: column;
    }
    main {
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
         -moz-box-flex: 1;
          -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
              flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
    .container {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 1rem;
    }
    footer {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
         -moz-box-flex: 0;
          -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
              flex: 0 0 auto;
      background-color: #eee;
      border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">This is main content</div>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="container">This is footer</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! That works. Just one more question: let's say I have a table in the main directive, how I can make it shrink, when user resizes window? I want the distance between bottom of the table and the bottom of page remain always the same.

Comment: You can have a minimum gap between it and the bottom by setting a `margin-bottom` to it. You can also center it vertically in the page, when the browser window allows it. But having the same distance from the footer... That's a bit of a strange request. What happens when the table is taller than the device? The top of the table gets cut off? Could you provide simple graphical representations of how it would look on a mobile and on a desktop? I'll try to code it.

Answer (score 1):

hi this is called as sticky footer, you can try this below code

```
html {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
}
body {
margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
#footer {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Demo here
http://mystrd.at/data/sticky_footer.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but I'm looking for footer that always on the screen, even when user resizes the window